# Google Chrome gives ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE error for HTTPS page (site is perfectly reachable via curl)

Tags: networking, google-chrome, https

A otherwise perfectly working Chrome browser gives an ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE error for a request to a https page on port 8443. The page is reachable via curl, Firefox, Safari..

How would I go about debugging this? To be honest I have no clue where to start (chrome dev tools network tab provides no useful information at all)..?

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Is the host using a self-signed certificate or commercial?

Answer (score 1):

You can snoop HTTPS session traffic by Wireshark and for example observe SSL handshake phase problems.
Please don't forget to add "host YOUR_HOST_NAME and port 8443" like filter to Wireshark to skip other traffic!